# Unable to post json data using postman in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, postman

What am I doing wrong here? I saw somewhere that body-parser is now inbuilt in express in express, I tried that also still the same result.
app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv/config");
const posts = require("./routes/posts");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//middleware to use "/posts" whenever we go to posts
app.use("/posts", posts);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //parsing json

//routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  //handle root
  res.send("We are home");
});

//how do we start listening/connect to the server
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => console.log("connected to DB!")
);

app.listen(3000);
```

Post.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Posts", PostSchema);
```

posts.js

```
const express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();
const Post = require("../models/Post");

//middleware
/*router.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.url, "@", Date.now());
    next();
})*/

router
  .route("/")
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    res.send("hi get /posts");
  })
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Terminal always shows that its undefined.

here's a screenshot of postman:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes bodyParser is included in the current versions of expressjs, and you can apply it like this:

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

Also this middleware must be applied before using routes. So the order must be like this:

```js
app.use(express.json()); //parsing json
app.use("/posts", posts);
```